# Find if a string is in or not in a database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a list of IDs

```
'ACE', 'ACD', 'IDs', 'IN','CD'
```

I also have a table similar to following structure

```
ID value
ACE  2
CED  3
ACD  4
IN   4
IN   4
```

I want a SQL query that returns a list of IDs that exists in the database and a list of IDs that does not in the database.

The return should be:

```
1.ACE, ACD, IN (exist)
2.IDs,CD (not exist)
```

my code is like this

```
select 
    ID,
    value
from db
where ID is in ( 'ACE', 'ACD', 'IDs', 'IN','CD')
```

however, the return is 1) super slow with all kinds of IDs 2) return multiple rows with the same ID. Is there anyway using postgresql to return 1) unique ID 2) make the running faster?

Comment: That's a _table_, not a _database_. A database typically consists of several tables.

Comment: Please declare your Postgres version and the actual table definition (`CREATE TABLE` script showing data types and constraints). Can there be duplicates in the list or in the table column? If so, how to deal with those?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no duplicates in table nor input, this query should do it:

```sql
SELECT t.id IS NOT NULL AS id_exists
     , array_agg(ids.id)
FROM   unnest(ARRAY['ACE','ACD','IDs','IN','CD']) ids(id)
LEFT   JOIN tbl t USING (id)
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Else, please define how to deal with duplicates on either side.

If the `LEFT JOIN` finds a matching row, the expression `t.id IS NOT NULL` is true. Else it's false. `GROUP BY 1` groups by this expression (1st in the `SELECT` list), `array_agg()` forms arrays for each of the two groups.
Related:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . Is this sufficient:

```
select ids.id,
       (exists (select 1 from table t where t.id = ids.id)
from unnest(array['ACE', 'ACD', 'IDs', 'IN','CD']) ids(id);
```

Comment: sorry it's not working, could you explain a little bit?